# Export data to Google Cloud Storage. Cloud SQL Export. Do not work at all

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I want to export from Google Cloud SQL with function Export, in a cloud bucket. But do not work at all. 
Nothing happen. There is a bug.

It's not first time when I made exports, but right now the export function do not work.

Any ideas?

[Explained with a Gif Desktop Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSDmX.gif)

Comment: Nice, -1, but can you say what is not clear? I made a GIF, pretty clear. Function export do not work.

Comment: Got the exact same problem. Click the button and nothing happens. Have successfully exported before.

Comment: The problem is not resolved. I tried again several times, I cloned the SQL server and tried from there but same problem. Export did not work.

Answer (score 1):

*The problem is generated by the settings of bucket where you try to export:*

To ***resolve export function issue***, please try the steps below:

1. Go to Cloud Storage and click the bucket you trying to export data from.
2. Click “Edit bucket”.
3. Select “Set object-level and bucket-level permissions” for “Access control model”.
4. Save the changes.
5. Configure/Try the export again.

Print screens:
[Step-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3L9M.png)
[Step-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jUvd.png)
[Step-2-with-custom-db-export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wy94.png)
[Final-Export-Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTY5J.png)

*A suggestion to Google Cloud Engineers is to post an error message or something when you try to export in a bucket with wrong Access Control Model.
Right now you don't have any clue what is happening.*

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem. It seems to be a bug with the GCP console.

A work around is to use the command line tool instead.

First you will need to give your cloudSQL service account permissions to access your bucket. Do this by copying the service account name and adding it on the bucket permissions in the GCP console. It will need Storage Object Creator permissions.

Next to export, use the following command.

```
gcloud sql export <<instancename>> gs://<<bucket name>>/<<file Name>>.gz —database=<<DB name>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around! It's nice to know this. I posted the steps how to solve this issue without GCP console. (the problem is that the bucket's now have to be with Access Control Model on “Set object-level and bucket-level permissions”.

Comment: Great. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks. Google really should put a message explaining this.